# Sprite not location when I click on the inspector window in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, inspector

When I click on the file name or sprite on the inspector window it should locate the file/sprite in project window with a yellow background. But when I am clicking on it, it is not locating the sprite as well as file. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

First, be on the Project Tab:

[image]

Then, click on the Text, or the image if the pop-up is open.
[image]

It should locate the file in "Project" Explorer.
This won't work if the file is not in your Project Hierarchy. Unity Default Meshes (primitives like Cube, Sphere...) for example cannot be located.

Make sure that you have only one "Project" window open and that it's not locked:
[image]

If that doesn't work, try restarting Unity or reset the Layouts:
[image]

Good Luck!

Comment: Glad I could help. Feel free to mark my answer as solution.

Comment: Thanks!! Resetting layout solved my problem, though I set layout as default which solved it instead of resetting it!